# Subscripts and superscripts breaking if used on mathematical formula contained by braces

Tags: macros, mathematics

If I contstruct two different commands capturing a subscription:

```
\newcommand{\nobraces}{a_b}
\newcommand{\braces}{{a_b}}
```

then the `\nobraces` version works according to expectations, when e.g. we want to append a superscript:

```
\nobraces^c \braces^c
```

produces:
$a_b^c {a_b}^c$

However, in certain instances, the command has to be encapsulated into a formula of its own, hence the `\braces` version is mandatory. E.g. when the command is used in a superscript itself:

```
d^\nobraces d^\braces
```

produces:
$d^a_b d^{a_b}$

Is there a way to create a robust version of the command that produces the expected result everywhere?

Comment: the latex syntax is _always_  `d^{\nobraces}` the fact that sometimes `^` works without bracing its argument is an undocumented accident of the implementation.    `d^{\nobraces}` and  `d^{\braces}` produce the same result

Comment: Interesting. Is there a official source for this?

Comment: On more extremely stupid question regarding formatting of questions here on stackexchange: why aren't my formulas renderred properly?

Comment: the latex book documents how to get a supercript and specified `x^{2}` if you discover by accident that `x^2` works, you are on your own.

Comment: we do not enable mathjax on this site (as it would be confusing as it's javascript not tex)

Comment: Thx for all the answers. Does your latest reply mean that on this particular site we would always have to printscreen and insert formulas after rendering it elsewhere?

Comment: yes although most systems allow you to clip directly a fragment of your viewer without having to print screen. mathjax is exceptionally useful for showing mathmatics so is used on the math and physics stackexhange, but here usually the actual math is less important and you want to show the result _of tex_

Comment: @atti6j Most nowadays pdf-viewers allow to make a selection and copy it to clipboard while at TeX LaTeX StackExchange when inserting the image you can paste from clipboard. || When at TeX LaTeX StackExchange inserting images, besides clipboard and .jpg-files you can also specify .gif-files. Sometimes I open pdf-file produced with LaTeX with multipage-document in GIMP (Gnu Image Manipulation Program), have pages as layers, have the layer-order reversed so that the 1st layer holds document's page 1, 2nd  layer holds document's page 2, etc, and export as gif-animation.

Comment: @UlrichDiez [ImageMagick may save you a few clicks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/112755).